# Build problems with SQLite3 on VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I try to build SQLite v3 from source using VS2010 and run into problems which I do not know how to tackle.

This is what I have:
VS2010 pro.
using sqlite-amalgamation-3160100.zip
Microsoft article: [SQLite databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases)

This is what I did:

1. Created a C++ 'Win32 Console application'.
2. Disabled procompiled headers.
3. Added preprocessor definitions: (**dont do this, this is the problem!**)
   _HAVE_SQLITE_CONFIG_H;SQLITE_OS_WINRT;SQLITE_API=__declspec(dllexport);
   (as specified by 'SQLite databases' section 3.)
4. Created config.h (which is empty for the moment.)
5. Included the source files from sqlite-amalgamation-3160100.zip in the project.
6. build.

I get a number of compiler errors

```
1>  sqlite3.c
1>e:\andre\ontwikkeling\sqlite\sqlite-amalgamation-3160100\sqlite3.c(38515): error C2065: 'MapViewOfFileFromApp' : undeclared identifier
1>e:\andre\ontwikkeling\sqlite\sqlite-amalgamation-3160100\sqlite3.c(38515): error C2099: initializer is not a constant
1>e:\andre\ontwikkeling\sqlite\sqlite-amalgamation-3160100\sqlite3.c(38524): error C2065: 'CreateFile2' : undeclared identifier
....
```

... which I try to solve.

The first one leads me to the following code snipped:

```
#if SQLITE_OS_WINRT && (!defined(SQLITE_OMIT_WAL) || SQLITE_MAX_MMAP_SIZE>0)
  { "MapViewOfFileFromApp",    (SYSCALL)MapViewOfFileFromApp,    0 },
#else
  { "MapViewOfFileFromApp",    (SYSCALL)0,                       0 },
#endif
```

Now 'MapViewOfFileFromApp' leads to [MapViewOfFileFromApp function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh994454(v=vs.85).aspx), 'Maps a view of a file mapping into the address space of a calling Windows Store app.', a valid microsoft call for which my project setup is missing the correct configuration.

I could get a workaround for this one, but other errors are depending only on SQLITE_OS_WINRT and as such not possible to work around it.

It looks like that I'm missing some configuration options but I do not know which ones. I read all of the documented [compile time options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) but can't find out what it is that I do wrong.

I tried to find a working exaple of a VS2010 solution but came up with nothing. And of cause I checked here for similar questions! (If there is one covering this then I missed it, sorry.)

Does anybody have a suggestion on what I'm missing? I'm running out of idea's.

*** edit 6 jan 2017 ***

On advice of MaxFurry I followed the steps of the [blog by David Cravey](https://dcravey.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/using-sqlite-in-a-visual-c-application/) which does exact the same steps as I did but without declaring `SQLITE_OS_WINRT;SQLITE_API=__declspec(dllexport);`. Leaving these two defines out solved the problem.

Aparently I misinterpreted the advice in the Microsoft article.

Compile time problems solved.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your sqlite3.dll file already built? If so just create a folder in your visual studio folder. When u want to use sqlite3 just copy the dll file to the folder of the project in visual studio u want to use it also copy the following files there sqlit3.c, sqlite3.h. When this is done open the project in your visual studio IDE. Right click on the project name, add, add existing then click on the sqlite3.h and sqlite3.c. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: ??? I just want to build the dll from the files! (sqlite3.c + sqlite3.h). Your answer does not make sense to me.

Comment: This are the exact steps I followed https://dcravey.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/using-sqlite-in-a-visual-c-application/

Comment: I'm not using the dll, I want to use it from the source file (alternative from step 11 in your link to the blog and I skip steps from 2 upto 6). I notice that this blog is not mentioning settings for SQLITE_OS_WINRT;SQLITE_API=__declspec(dllexport); as mentioned in the microsoft article. Not setting SQLITE_OS_WINRT solved my problem.